# find and display element from the ajax file

Tags: jquery

Consider this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "misc/moreactivities.php",
    data: { lastmsg : ID, pid: pid },  
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $("#profileWall").append(html);
        $("#more"+ID).remove();
    }
});
```

Right now it appends everything that is output in `moreactivities.php`. I only want to append the `div#moreactivity` element from within it.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `html` that's returned as the [context](http://api.jquery.com/context/) for a `#moreactivity` selector, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "misc/moreactivities.php",
  data: { lastmsg : ID, pid: pid },  
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#moreactivity", html).appendTo("#profileWall");
    $("#more"+ID).remove();
  }
});
```

Instead of appending *all* the HTML, this looks for the `#moreactivity` element inside it and appends *that* to `#profileWall`.

Comment: Hello. the #more removes, and nothing appends to #profileWall.

Comment: @Karem - can you clarify a bit? are you sure there's a `id="moreactivity"` in the response?

Comment: Doublechecked. There is id="moreactivity" in the response.